# What does ホッチキスでとめる mean?

Tags: grammar

I have a difficulty to translate ホッチキスでとめる.

- ホッチキス means stapler
- で means with
- とめる means stop

Stop with stapler? What?

Comment: Even free online dictionaries give us more definitions for [とめる](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%AD%A2%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B) than just "stop".

Comment: @l'électeur: I used google: https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to be more creative ;)

It just means

> to staple (something) together

If the `とめる` would be written in Kanji, it gets `留める`, which is more like "hold","keep".

Comment: Ah - so that explains 前髪とめ〜る.